# GEO IP based redirection for Website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have IP based redirection for our website and its working perfectly. 
Only the problem is I have put 301 redirect for nonwww to  www urls, so in this case what happens is it creates 2 redirect first for WWW and second IP based redirection.

So I want to minimize this to single IP based redirection, can anybody tell me how can achieve this.

thanks

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: It would be nice to provide some details about how you do the geo ip redirection.

Comment: I am doing this from javascript using maxmind service.
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can handle redirecting in one place. If you are using PHP, let use PHP to redirect both of 301 nonWWW and IP location.